# Rerender apex:details after DML async method call

Tags: visualforce, asynchronous, rerender

I have found a strange behaviour and I can't find why does it happening. I have custom object Test2_*c with custom text field Status*_c. I want to change it's status asynchronously, so I prepare a VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Test2__c" extensions="test2ExtController">
  <apex:form id="someform">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!statusClose}" value="Close" 
       rendered="{!Test2__c.Status__c == 'Open'}" rerender="someform"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!statusOpen}" value="Reopen" 
       rendered="{!Test2__c.Status__c == 'Closed'}" rerender="someform" />

    <apex:detail id="detail"/>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and controller extension:

```
public class test2ExtController {
  private final Apexpages.Standardcontroller stdController ;

  public void statusClose() {
   SObject obj = stdController.getRecord();
   obj.put('Status__c', 'Closed');
   update obj;
  }
  public void statusOpen() {        
   SObject obj = stdController.getRecord();
   obj.put('Status__c', 'Open');
   update obj;
  }
  public test2ExtController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    stdController = controller;
  }
}
```

Now strange things are happening:

1. I click the button -> status is updated, buttons are rerendered, BUT `<apex:details>` remain the same
2. I click the second button -> status is updated, buttons are rerendered AND `<apex:details>` are rerendered but in a WRONG way. It reflect changes made in step 1!!!

From this behaviour i conclude, that `<apex:details>` IS rerendered but BEFORE the object is updated and buttons are rerendered AFTER object is updated. **Why?**

Am I making something wrong? How can I get details refreshed after async update call?

Comment: So does it sound like the apex:detail is typical one change off?

Comment: you're code looks perfect, the answers may give you some work arounds, but for the sake of future developers, can you log a case with support so they're aware of the issue and reference this stackexchange post?

Answer (score 4):

This is just a workaround.  Like @Ralph commented, your code looks like it should work, so you might want to contact support.

Create an [`apex:actionFunction`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) that reRenders a section containing the detail and then call that function from the oncomplete of the [`apex:commandButton`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm).

```
<apex:page standardController="Test2__c" extensions="test2ExtController">
  <apex:form id="someform">

    <apex:commandButton action="{!statusClose}" value="Close" 
       rendered="{!Test2__c.Status__c == 'Open'}" rerender="someform" 
       oncomplete="getDetailSection();" />

    <apex:commandButton action="{!statusOpen}" value="Reopen" 
       rendered="{!Test2__c.Status__c == 'Closed'}" 
       oncomplete="getDetailSection();"/>

    <apex:outputPanel id="detailContainer">
        <apex:detail id="detail"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>

  </apex:form>

  <apex:actionFunction name="getDetailSection" reRender="detailContainer"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: works fine, will file the bug anyways. the only thing now is that if apex:details has relatedLists="true", it hides quicklinks to them usually displayed over details.

Answer (score 2):

First it is not a good idea to rerender a form object. For that use `apex:outputPanel`, it is much comfortable.

Second thing is, use `PageReference` methods for the action on the command button.

So your code will look like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Test2__c" extensions="test2ExtController">
    <apex:form id="someform">

        <apex:outputPanel id="mainBlock">

            <apex:commandButton action="{!statusClose}" 
                  value="Close" 
                  rendered="{!Test2__c.Status__c == 'Open'}" 
                  reRender="mainBlock"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!statusOpen}" 
                  value="Reopen" 
                  rendered="{!Test2__c.Status__c == 'Closed'}" 
                  reRender="mainBlock" />

            <apex:detail id="detail"/>

        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class test2ExtController {
    private final Apexpages.Standardcontroller stdController ;

    public PageReference statusClose() {
        SObject obj = stdController.getRecord();
        obj.put('Status__c', 'Closed');
        try{
            update obj;
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        return null;
    }
    public PageReference statusOpen() {        
        SObject obj = stdController.getRecord();
        obj.put('Status__c', 'Open');
        try{
            update obj;
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        return null;
    }
    public test2ExtController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        stdController = controller;
    }
}
```

Comment: While general suggestions are useful, these changes aren't getting apex:details to rerender correctly :(

Comment: @mast0r can you elaborate on why it's not good to rerender a form object?  Just curious since I do this all the time and haven't heard of any issues, and would love to know if this is something I should be changing.