# Rerender an apex:component

Tags: visualforce-component, rerender

I have a component within an outputPanel like this:

```
    <apex:panelGrid columns="5" id="theDataGrid">
          <c:GraphAndTable whichData="leadByRep" description="Description 1"/>
    <apex:panelGrid>
```

I have this action function that triggers the rerender (I checked it works fine)

```
    <apex:actionFunction name="selectDateRange" rerender="theDataGrid" >
            <apex:param name="dateParam" assignTo="{!mSelectedDateFilter}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

**Problem**: although the panelGrid is reRendered the component inside does not.
Is there anyway to cause the component to reRender as well?

Comment: Has anyone solved this conundrum? I'm stuck with two components that contain buttons and output panels, but they won't rerender `apex:outputPanel` components, even though they're inside the same `apex:component` definition.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised this doesn't work but then I can't remember if I've ever tried it.

Given the global nature of javascript variables and elements used in components you could put an `<apex:outputPanel>` inside your component wrapping everything else, and give it a particular ID.

Then specify that ID in the rerender attribute of the `<apex:actionFunction>` as well.

Comment: This didn't work either, I'm now looking into other possible causes for my component table not showing the right data. Originally I thought it is because of the rerender but I'm starting to look at other directions. Will update

Comment: Does that mean it *is* re-rendering? I'd use a very simple boolean variable or something to check that.

Answer (score 4):

I would've expected it to rerender.  The [Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Postback Requests](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_postback_request.htm) would lead me to believe that the component's controller set methods should be called and the view state should be updated.  This seems similar to the recently asked question on [apex:details not rerendering](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/rerender-apexdetails-after-dml-async-method-call/8866).

You could reRender the component on the onComplete of the actionFunction, similar to [a workaround for the apex:details issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8866/154).

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="5" id="theDataGrid">
    <apex:outputPanel id="componentContainer">
      <c:GraphAndTable whichData="leadByRep" description="Description 1"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
<apex:panelGrid>


<apex:actionFunction 
    name="selectDateRange" 
    rerender="theDataGrid" 
    oncomplete="updateComponent();">
        <apex:param name="dateParam" assignTo="{!mSelectedDateFilter}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="updateComponent" reRender="componentContainer"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you're not the only one who has come across this issue.

> ...The solution is to nest the conditionally rendered output panel inside
>   another output panel and change the command button to rerender that.
>   The containing output panel will always be present on the page and
>   thus the Ajax request will be able to update it on completion. The
>   inner component may or may not be rendered depending on the value...

I grabbed the preceeding snippet from this blog post: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html

Comment: This solution solved a different problem, that of re-rendering a conditionally rendered element. The issue being that if an element is not rendered then it's not in the markup and hence can't be used for a rerender.  The question is asking specifically about rerendering `<apex:component>`.

Comment: Thanks Jonny, this link actually solved a different problem I was having and didn't get around to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, the solution for me was to create an outputPanel around the component and rerender that instead of the component itself.