# Hide object details on visualforce page until condition met

Tags: visualforce

My salesforce application ties custom salesforce records to actions on an external server. Because of this I want to hide record details upon record creation until the external resource is available (this is an asynchronous operation that can take a few seconds).

The following code mostly accomplishes what I want, but when the outputPanel refreshes the apex:detail components title and chatter bar aren't displayed. However, if do a browser refresh the title and chatter components appear.

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="CustomObjectExtension">
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel id="mainBlock" >
        <c:BusyIndicator rendered="{!waitingOnResource}" />
        <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages"/>
        <apex:detail showChatter="true"  relatedList="true" rendered="{!waitingOnResource == false}" subject="{!recordId}/>
        <apex:actionPoller reRender="mainBlock" interval="5" enabled="{!waitingOnResource}" action="{!refreshAndUpdateData}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

**Question:** Why don't the title and chatter components get displayed when the apex:detail object gets rendered?

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Are you sure `resourceReady` is being updated correctly? Also it's name is misleading, seems like it's `true` when the resource is NOT ready! Maybe try wrapping the components to hide in an output panel that isn't rendered initially, and then showing that. Shouldn't really make a difference but seem like you've hit some odd behavior.

Comment: No, the logic is correct, but was poorly named. I re-named some variables before posting here to protect my clients identity and got the action named backwards.

I have updated the variable name to make sense.

Comment: It doesn't seem right that your apex:detail would reRender in a partial manner.  There was a similar [issue with rerenders and apex:detail](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/rerender-apexdetails-after-dml-async-method-call) not reRendering in an expected manner.

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple browsers? E.G. Is it only happening in say I.E. 8, but not in Chrome or Firefox?? This could easily be a browser specific issue.

Comment: That was one of the first things that occurred to me. I've tested this using the latest chrome, firefox and IE. All have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on chatter dynamic rerender. The console shows me an error on dynimic loading of Ext lib.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined Chatter.js:13
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHovers' of undefined ChatterDefer.js:35
```

I've solved this using an small script to reload the entire page and setting that variable on `refreshAndUpdateData` method:

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!reload}" id="reloadBlock">
  <script>location.reload();</script>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Is not the most elegant solution but works for me.